# $http Interceptor is not invoking on response error

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, interceptor

This is my Upload-Update page and when response is 401 its not automatically invoking `app.init` [http interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) code. Instead `$scope.close()` i tried many thing i know i have to change `$scope.close()` to invoke interceptor but need to change i m not getting for other scenario its automatically interceptor :

```
angular.module('Myapp')
.controller('CatalogueUploadDialogCtrl', [ '$scope', '$window', '$location', '$log', 'dialog', 'UiService', 'I18nService', 'ApiErrorHandlerService', 'EntitySaveService',
    function($scope, $window, $location, $log, dialog, uiService, i18n, apiErrorHandler, entitySaveService) {
        $scope.close = function() {
            dialog.close(); 
        }

        $scope.isOpenDisabled = function() {
            return ($scope.formController && $scope.formController.inProgress())
                || !($scope.model && $scope.model.file && $scope.model.file.name);
        }

        $scope.open = function($event) {
            if(!$scope.isOpenDisabled()) {
                entitySaveService.flush()
                    .then(function() {
                        $scope.formController.submit()
                            .then(
                                function success(classLibraryHandle) {
                                    $scope.classLibraryHandle = classLibraryHandle;
                                    $scope.close();
                                },
                                function (response) {
                                    // I've found no good way to reset the formController;
                                    // closing the dialog on error.
                                    $scope.close();
                                });

                        });
            }
        }
    }
])
```

----------------Http interceptor code in app.init.js page-------------

```
.config([ '$httpProvider', function($httpProvider, i18n) {
    var handling401;

    // Add header to allow server side to detect XHR request
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push([ '$q', '$window', '$log', '$injector', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'I18nService', 'ApiErrorHandlerService', 'SessionService',
        function ($q, $window, $log, $injector, $rootScope, $timeout, i18n, apiErrorHandler, session) {
            return function (promise) {
                return promise.then(
                    function httpSuccess(response) {
                        if(response && response.data && response.data === 'null') {
                            response.data = null;
                        }
                        return response;
                    },
                    function httpError(response) {
                        function resolveMessage(data) {
                            var msg;
                            _.each([ 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'title'], function(tag) {
                                var pattern = '<' + tag + '[^>]*>([^<]*)';
                                var match = new RegExp(pattern).exec(data);
                                if(match) {
                                    msg = match[1];
                                }
                            });
                            return msg;
                        }

                        // Identity Provider Token timeout handling
                        var innerScope, $dialog;
                        if(response.status === 401 || response.status === 404 && response.data === '') {
                            if(!handling401) {
                                // The token refresh will cause a new 401. Because of this
                                // we need to prevent 401 handling while a 401 handle is
                                // in progress.
                                handling401 = true;

                                innerScope = $rootScope.$new();
                                innerScope.error = resolveMessage(response.data);

                                $dialog = $injector.get('$dialog');
                                $dialog.dialog({
                                    // We need to keep this HTML inline because if the
                                    // client authentication token have timed out, we will
                                    // be unable to query the view using templateUrl
                                    template:   '<div class="modal-header"> \
                                                            <h3>{{ \'authentication-failed.dialog.header\' | i18n }}</h3> \
                                                        </div> \
                                                        <div class="modal-body"> \
                                                            <div class="modal-body-inner"> \
                                                                <div ng-show="!loaded"> \
                                                                    <i class="icon-spinner"></i> {{ \'authentication-failed.dialog.refreshing\' | i18n }} \
                                                                </div> \
                                                                <div ng-show="iframe.status == \'fail\'" class="alert alert-error"> \
                                                                    <h4>{{ \'authentication-failed.dialog.refresh-failed\' | i18n }}</h4> \
                                                                    <span ng-if="error"><small>{{ \'reason\' | i18n }}:<br />{{ error }}</small></span> \
                                                                </div> \
                                                                <div ng-show="iframe.status == \'success\'" class="alert alert-info"> \
                                                                    <h4>{{ \'authentication-failed.dialog.refresh-successful\' | i18n }}</h4> \
                                                                </div> \
                                                                <iframe av-authentication-iframe="iframe.status" style="width:500px;height:100px;display:none"></iframe> \
                                                            </div> \
                                                        </div> \
                                                        <div class="modal-footer"> \
                                                            <button type="button" ng-if="iframe.status == \'fail\'" onclick="location.reload(false)" class="btn">{{ \'reload\' | i18n }}</button> \
                                                            <button type="button" ng-if="iframe.status == \'success\'" ng-click="close()" class="btn">{{ \'close\' | i18n }}</button> \
                                                        </div>',
                                    controller: 'AuthenticationFailedDialogCtrl',
                                    resolve: {
                                        $scope: function() {
                                            return innerScope;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).open()
                                    .finally(function() {
                                        innerScope.$destroy();
                                        innerScope = null;
                                        handling401 = false;
                                    });
                            }

                            return $q.reject(response);
                        }

                        // License handling
                        if(response.status === 402) {
                            if(!$window.licenseDialogOpen) {
                                $window.licenseDialogOpen = true;

                                innerScope = $rootScope.$new();
                                innerScope.error = response.data;

                                $dialog = $injector.get('$dialog');
                                $dialog.dialog({
                                    templateUrl: 'views/license-invalid-dialog.html',
                                    controller: 'DialogCtrl',
                                    resolve: {
                                        $scope: function() {
                                            return innerScope;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).open()
                                    .finally(function() {
                                        innerScope.$destroy();
                                        innerScope = null;
                                        $window.licenseDialogOpen = false;
                                    });
                            }
                            return $q.reject(response);
                        }

                        if (response.status === 409 && apiErrorHandler.isExtensionNamespaceError(response.data)) {
                            if(apiErrorHandler.isError(response.data)) {
                                apiErrorHandler.handle(response.data);
                            }
                            return $q.reject(response.status);
                        }

                        $log.error('--> Intercepted failed HTTP response', response);

                        if(response) {
                            if(apiErrorHandler.isError(response.data)) {
                                apiErrorHandler.handle(response.data);
                            }
                            // Ignore the error if it's an IgnoreError instance
                            else if(response.data != apiErrorHandler.IgnoreError()) {
                                if(response.data && response.data.ExceptionMessage) {
                                    $window.alert('ExceptionType: ' + response.data.ExceptionType + '\n\n' +
                                        'ExceptionMessage: ' + response.data.ExceptionMessage + '\n\n');
                                } else {
                                    if(response.status === 0) {
                                        $log.info('Ignoring aborted XHR request.');
                                    } else {
                                        var msg = 'An unknown error with status "' + (response.status || response) + '" occurred.';
                                        if(response && response.data) {
                                            if(typeof response.data == 'string') {
                                                msg = resolveMessage(response.data);
                                            } else if(response.data.Message) {
                                                msg = response.data.Message;
                                                if(response.data.MessageDetail) {
                                                    msg += "\n\n" + response.data.MessageDetail;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        $log.error(msg);
                                        $window.alert(msg);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        return $q.reject(response);
                    });
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

The interceptor is malformed. The constructor function should return an object, not a function:

```
$httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push([ '$q', '$window', '$log', '$injector', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'I18nService', 'ApiErrorHandlerService', 'SessionService',
  function ($q, $window, $log, $injector, $rootScope, $timeout, i18n, apiErrorHandler, session) {
      ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶p̶r̶o̶m̶i̶s̶e̶)̶ ̶{̶
      return {
        // optional method
        'request': function(config) {
          // do something on success
          return config;
        },

        // optional method
       'requestError': function(rejection) {
          // do something on error
          if (canRecover(rejection)) {
            return responseOrNewPromise
          }
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        },    

        // optional method
        'response': function(response) {
          // do something on success
          return response;
        },

        // optional method
       'responseError': function(rejection) {
          // do something on error
          if (canRecover(rejection)) {
            return responseOrNewPromise
          }
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
      };
}]);
```

For more information, see [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors).